# Core Data populated in Simulator but not moving to Device

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I've found lots of explanations and help here on stack but so far, no luck.

Pretty much, my myapp.sqlite (that I pre-populated) works fine on the simulator but when I run it on the iPad, it's empty.

So after trying different things, this is the closest I got :

- I copy the sqlite db into the Bundle but I move it to the Library folder.

On my AppDelegate I do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSLog(@"Starting to save the DB to another location");

    NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *targetPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDB.sqlite"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:targetPath]) {
        // database doesn't exist in your library path... copy it from the bundle
        NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        NSError *error = nil;

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:targetPath error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }


    return YES;
}
```

then on the PersistentStoreCoordinator, I do this

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *targetPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDB.sqlite"];

//    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"naccApp.sqlite"];
//    NSURL *storeURLLocal = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myDB" withExtension:@"sqlite"];

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:targetPath];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

When I try to use the DB, (fetchRequest), I get an error :

CoreData SQL stores only support file URLs (got /var/mobile/Applications/2EB2AADD-DF9D-475F-A05E-BB138502471F/Library/myDB.sqlite).

The message is clear but I've tried almost all the help here and still nothing.

Needless to say, I'm new to Core Data, so please forgive the ignorance.

Oh, I'm using xCode 5.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:targetPath];
```

Should be:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:targetPath];
```

so that you generate a file URL instead of a web URL.

Comment: Worked... finally! Thank you for spotting that.